# How to import database to each site in WordPress Multi site?

Tags: wordpress

I have WordPress multisite contains four sites, mean I have four different databases within PHPMyAdmin, for example, I have four wp_posts table like this (wp_posts, wp_2_posts, wp_3_posts, and wp_4_posts) also I Exported the data from localhost Wamp server I want to import the database to all four sites from PHPMyAdmin. How can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question it is not correct that way you described in your question it is very difficult I think the best way to do that until each site have the same posts in the database you need

**First:** import the database as `XML` file extension from your localhost server. from your Wordpress dashboard admin panel go to **Tools->Export** then select **All content** then click on **Download Export File** to download all posts as an `XML` file

**Second:** Then go to your Wordpress multisite **Import** XML xml file to each sites that you created within wordpress multisite. From admin dashboard go to **Tools->Import** then install WordPress import plugin Then import XML file Click on **Choose File** then click on **Upload file and import**  button Until import all database to your new site from localhost server XML file

Comment: Thanks, @SAFEEN 1990 your way it is the correct way thanks again for the help